# Reading a line from a socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I am writing some code in which i need to get a line from a socket whenever the line ends in a newline or carriage return. The line shoould be stored in a buffer.

```
 n = recv(sock, &ch, 1, 0);
  if (n > 0)
  {
   if (ch == '\r')
   {
       // do stuff
   }
     //
  }
   //
```

I am using code like this inside a while but it is not working any clues How can i do this.

Edited: I want one line to be read from the socket and returned to be parsed. This should hap[pen for each line read.

Comment: You're going to need to supply a more complete code sample than that, and/or a better description of what you mean by "not working" (what do you expect to happen, and what is actually happening).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is similar to the recent question entitled "getline over a socket".

The answer is that you should not do this.  What would happen if the client did not send the next line?  Your program would hang.

From your code snippet, you do not appear to be checking the error codes.  These would indicate why your code is "nor working" and would indicate where to start looking for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1)  Maybe you have carriage return / linefeed?

2)  Maybe ch is overflowing?

3)  Maybe your stream is binary and \r is valid for non-EOL?